# Removing already drawn object THREE

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I´m trying to make a code for spline observation.My problem is, I've created a menu so I can choose between splines, however when I select the next one, the spline that has been drawn before doesn´t disappears even though I tried to remove from the scene.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Brincando </title>
      <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script>
      var camera, cameraControls,scene,renderer,dropdown,container,info;
      var numPoints = 100;
  
      sampleSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 200, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(150, 150, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(150, 50, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(250, 100, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(250, 300, 0)
      ]);
  
      sampleSpline2 = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, -200, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(-150, -150, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(-150, -50, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(-250, -100, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(-250, -300, 0)
      ]);

      sampleSpline.type='catmullrom';
      sampleSpline2.type='catmullrom';
  
      var splines ={
        sampleSpline: sampleSpline,
        sampleSpline2: sampleSpline2
      };
  
      var dropdown = '<select id="dropdown" onchange="addSpline(this.value)">';
      var s;
      for ( s in splines ) {
        dropdown += '<option value="' + s + '"';
        dropdown += '>' + s + '</option>';
      }
      dropdown += '</select>';

      function addSpline(){
  
        var value = document.getElementById('dropdown').value;
        var selectspline = splines[value];
  
        if(line)
        {
          scene.remove(line);
        }
  
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
          color: 0xff00f0,
        });

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var splinePoints = selectspline.getPoints(numPoints);

        for(var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++)
        {
          geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);  
        }
 
        var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
        scene.add(line);
  
      }
  
      init();
      animate();
  
      function init()
      {
        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);
  
        info = document.createElement('div');
        info.style.position = 'absolute';
        info.style.top = '10px';
        info.style.width = '100%';
        info.style.textAlign = 'center';
        info.innerHTML = dropdown;
        container.appendChild(info);
  
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
 
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,10000);
        camera.position.z= 700;
  
        cameraControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera,renderer.domElement)
  
        cameraControls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
        cameraControls.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
  
        cameraControls.noZoom = false;
        cameraControls.noPan = true;
  
        cameraControls.staticMoving = true;
        cameraControls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
  
        cameraControls.addEventListener('change',render);
  
        scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
  
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 
        addSpline();
 
        renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd, 1);

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
  
        render();
      }
 
      function onWindowResize() 
      {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        cameraControls.handleResize();
        render();
      }
 
 
      function animate() 
      {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        cameraControls.update();
      }
      function render()
      {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      }
  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the THREE library isn´t defined there, and I don´t know to to attach it to the code, so if you have problems with that, just tell me how to do it and I will do it as soon as possible.=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `line` variable is local for the `addSpline` function,

the code

```
if(line)
{
   scene.remove(line);
}
```

will always see line as undefined, move the line variable declaration to other global variables

`var camera, cameraControls, scene, renderer, dropdown, container,info,` **line**;

and remove the var declaration from inside the function

<strike>var</strike> `line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);`

you should also dispose of the material, not overuse global variables etc but that is out of scope of this question